# Save downloaded file to iCloud Drive with Safari on iOS8

Tags: icloud, ios, mobile-safari

I would like to download a simple text file using Safari on my iPad and save it to iCloud Drive. However, there is no "Open in..." options in Safari to save to iCloud Drive.

I have an iPad2 with iOS8 and I have upgraded to iCloud Drive.

Then, I would like to be able to select this same file in iCloud Drive so that I can upload it to a website using Safari on my iPad2 on iSO8. Right now, the only files I can upload are from the camera roll or take a new picture/video.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who comes acros this question via Google or some other search engine, there is a way!

The most excellent app, Workflow, once again comes to the rescue.  You can create a file downloading workflow that works perfectly:

http://www.guidingtech.com/36337/file-downloader-safari-ios-8/

I'm on iOS 9 and works great.  I really need to pay attention to Workflow more - it really is the glue that solves many of the little niggling edge cases for iOS lacking what is easily done on a desktop.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry, you can't manually upload files to iCloud from your iPad. You can only upload files to your iCloud Drive using a Mac.. 
OR any computer.